# What is the (fnptr)* type and how to create it?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, cil

The following IL code creates a Type instance named `(fnptr)*` (token 0x2000000 - invalid, module mscorlib.dll).

```
ldtoken method void* ()*
call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
```

What's the purpose of this type? Is it possible to create this type instance in C# without writing any IL code, maybe with reflection? *Module.ResolveType* on the token throws *ArgumentOutOfRangeException*.

Edit:

It's clear the `(fnptr)` type is an internal CLR type representation of an IL method pointer type, though when removing the last `*`, it simply returns `IntPtr`.

Edit #2:

The `(fnptr)` comes from a function that can be seen in the [SSCLI](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) *typestring.cpp*:

> ```
> // ...or function pointer
> else if (ty.IsFnPtrType())
> {
>     // Don't attempt to format this currently, it may trigger GC due to fixups.
>     tnb.AddName(L"(fnptr)");
> }
> ```

Why basic fnptr returns IntPtr can be seen in *typehandle.cpp*:

> ```
> OBJECTREF TypeHandle::GetManagedClassObject() const
> {
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>         switch(GetInternalCorElementType()) {
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_ARRAY:
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY:
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_BYREF:
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_PTR:
>             return ((ParamTypeDesc*)AsTypeDesc())->GetManagedClassObject();
>
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_VAR:
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_MVAR:
>             return ((TypeVarTypeDesc*)AsTypeDesc())->GetManagedClassObject();
>
>             // for this release a function pointer is mapped into an IntPtr. This result in a loss of information. Fix next release
>         case ELEMENT_TYPE_FNPTR:
>             return TheIntPtrClass()->GetManagedClassObject();
>
>         default:
>         _ASSERTE(!"Bad Element Type");
>         return NULL;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

So it looks they've forgotten to fix it.

Comment: Interesting. How did you come across this? From C++/CLI generated code?

Comment: @leppie Yeah, I just had an idea to look at C++/CLI assembly in ildasm and saw `*()*` there. This attracted my attention so I've created the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to load the signature of a *pointer to a* function pointer:

```
public static unsafe Type GetTypeFromFieldSignature(byte[] signature, Type declaringType = null)
{
    declaringType = declaringType ?? typeof(object);
    Type sigtype = typeof(Type).Module.GetType("System.Signature");
    Type rtype = typeof(Type).Module.GetType("System.RuntimeType");
    var ctor = sigtype.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[]{typeof(void*), typeof(int), rtype}, null);
    fixed(byte* ptr = signature)
    {
        object sigobj = ctor.Invoke(new object[]{(IntPtr)ptr, signature.Length, declaringType});
        return (Type)sigtype.InvokeMember("FieldType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, sigobj, null);
    }
}

var fnptrPtr = GetTypeFromFieldSignature(new byte[]{6, 15, 27, 0, 0, 1});
```

6 is field, 15 is pointer, 27 is function pointer and 0, 0, 1 is a method signature without return or parameters.

Answer (score 5):

I have no real idea what you are asking and why you think there is anything wrong.  (fnptr)* is the type name of a pointer to an unmanaged function pointer.  That it gets special treatment in the CLR is indeed odd, I suspect it is an archeological artifact.  Dating back to a time before .NET and before delegates were invented.  The CLR started life as the "universal runtime" in Project 42, a failed project before .NET.

Maybe some C++/CLI code to demonstrate how to generate one is useful, shows you how to create it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

typedef void (*functionPointer)(int);

ref class Example {
public:
    functionPointer* fp;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto field = Example::typeid->GetField("fp");
    auto name = field->FieldType->FullName; 
    Console::WriteLine(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `(fnptr)*`

Comment: Thanks, it is possible in C++/CLI, but can it be done in pure C#?

Comment: No, you can't declare unmanaged function pointers in C#, it only supports delegates.  Very hard to guess why you'd ask this btw, I have absolutely no clue what your intentions might be.

Comment: I mean I just want to obtain the Type instance. And the reason? Curiosity. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're seeing the FNPTR being declared.

For this code:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}

.assembly Test
{
    .ver 1:0:1:0
}
.module test.exe

.method static void main() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint

    ldtoken method void* ()*
    call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)

    ldtoken method void* ()
    call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)

    ret
}
```

ILASM (4.5.22.0) outputs the following:

```
.method privatescope static void  main$PST06000001() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldtoken    method void *()*
  IL_0005:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_000a:  ldtoken    method void *()
  IL_000f:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_0014:  ret
} // end of method 'Global Functions'::main
```

## Update #1:

Perhaps I am being dense here, but I am not seeing FNPTR being generated from this code:

```
typeof(StringBuilder).ToString();
```

The IL looks like this:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldtoken    [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder
IL_0006:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_000b:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
IL_0010:  pop
IL_0011:  ret
```

The `Type.ToString()` call is a `callvirt` operation since [ToString() is a virtual method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Virtual functions are usually manifested as structs of function pointers which would, I guess, result in a FNPTR being emitted. If you omit the `*` in `()*` resulting in `()`, you're now describing a function, not a function pointer.

What version of .NET are you using when you see the FNPTR? What are you using to extract the IL?

Comment: The CLR outputs `(fnptr)*` from Type.ToString.

Comment: Again, if you compile the code I posted in my question, it returns a Type, which, being called ToString on, returns `(fnptr)*`.

Comment: I did compile your code - see my 1st sample and the resulting output. Can you post a repro'?

Comment: And you see my first and second answer. And I wonder where you've found `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering in the context of C# 9 ‒ functions pointers are now possible to represent and consume directly, via the `delegate*` syntax. However, the runtime (.NET 7) still has the same limitations it had 7 years ago:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(typeof(delegate*<void>)); // IntPtr
Console.WriteLine(typeof(delegate*<void>*)); // (fnptr)*
```