# How to interpret FNPTR from Type blob signature?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, bytecode, cil

How should I interpret FNPTR followed by a MethodDefSig or by a MethodRefSig? I mean that BOOLEAN is bool, OBJECT is object, SZARRAY is a zero-based array, but FNPTR have a method signature and I can't write something like:

```
public static int*(int) myFunction();
```

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: Perhaps related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27195502/613130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FNPTR is a signature element denoting a low-level pointer to a managed function which can be used by the `calli` opcode, for example. As far as I know, only C++/CLI has a use for them (to support standard C++ function pointers and references), and I suppose low-level languages were the reason they were included in CIL in the first place.

Despite being a core feature of CLI, there is zero support for them in the reflection API (apart from [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195502/what-is-the-fnptr-type-and-how-to-create-it)). They have no actual use apart from creating a distinct signature for method overloads, so you can safely use IntPtr if you are able to.

Function pointers are basically a low-level equivalent of delegates, only without the target object (and not being objects themselves). If you need a high-level equivalent, *Action* and *Func* delegates might be sufficient.

Comment: I should also mention that my library, [SharpUtils](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils), contains a variety of helper methods for signatures, as well as a type system extension supporting function pointer types.