# What is the difference between delegate in c# and function pointer in c++?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [are there function pointers in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738850/are-there-function-pointers-in-c)

I'm interested in finding the difference between [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in C# and [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) in C++.

Comment: Well, one is from C# and the other from C/C++.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't C++ (or at least stl) have delegates as well?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A delegate in C# is a type-safe function pointer with a built in iterator.

It's guaranteed to point to a valid function with the specified signature (unlike C where pointers can be cast to point to who knows what).  It also supports the concept of iterating through multiple bound functions.

In C#, delegates are *multi-cast* meaning they can iterate through multiple functions.  For example:

```
class Program
{
   delegate void Foo();

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Foo myDelegate = One;
      myDelegate += Two;

      myDelegate(); // Will call One then Two
   }

   static void One()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("In one..");
   }

   static void Two()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("In two..");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I'd say yes and no. You can specify the return type and parameters for a function pointer, which does many of the things you mentioned. The only exception I can think of is if you cast it to a void*.

Comment: Yea I guess it's more of a language/runtime difference.  All managed pointers are "safe", the runtime protects what they point to and you can't just go increment them or re-interpret them however you wish.  Sure, there's "unsafe" code in C# but that's another topic)

Comment: Modified my answer slightly to make it more clear..

Comment: `supports the concept of iterating through multiple bound functions.` -- What does that mean?  You can't do that with C++?

Comment: I don't think you're right about the iterator aspect.  It is true that a delegate is a type-safe function, but it doesn't contain an iterator out of the box; although you can use one with an iterator.  Can you explain what you mean by that in more detail?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.23_and_other_.NET_languages

Comment: .NET has unicast and multicast delegates.  Multicast delegates implement the `+=` and '-=` operators to add and remove methods from the invocation list.  All delegates you create in C# are multicast delegates.

Comment: @Mike: Right, "Multicast Delegates" is the correct terminology.  You can talk about "iterating" through the subscribed functions and calling them, but that's really obscure, and it doesn't have much relevance to the average C# developer, since the manner in which the functions are called is an internal implementation detail (I'm not even sure it uses the usual iterator mechanism, although that seems plausible).

Comment: Lemme post an example to make it a bit more clear..  I meant the `delegate` keyword in C# is multicast (this may or may not be the case in other .NET languages).  Sure, you can implement multicast delegates in C++ - You can implement anything you want :)

Comment: Behavior/usage if the delegate/functions return values: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12530767/1995714

Answer (score 8):

Delegates in C# can be either synchronous or asynchronous; C++ function pointers are synchronous unless you write your own multi-threading capability.

A pointer in C/C++ needn't refer to a full-blown object.  C had function pointers and no object-oriented language support.   Delegates are true function objects.