# Using a Multicast Delegate to chain functions

Tags: c#, delegates

My question is detailed in the following code - the reason I'm asking this is that I'm experimenting with delegates:

```
//create the delegate          
delegate int del(int x);

class Program {


    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program p;
        p = new Program();

        del d = p.a;
        d += p.b;
        d += p.c;
        d += p.d;
        d += p.e;
        Console.WriteLine(d(10)); //<<was hoping it would be 10+2+3+4+5+6

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private int a(int x) { Console.WriteLine("a is called"); return x + 2; }
    private int b(int x) { Console.WriteLine("b is called"); return x + 3; }
    private int c(int x) { Console.WriteLine("c is called"); return x + 4; }
    private int d(int x) { Console.WriteLine("d is called"); return x + 5; }
    private int e(int x) { Console.WriteLine("e is called"); return x + 6; }

}
```

16 is returned....

[image]

All the functions fire, as the various messages "a is called" etc all get printed to the `console` but only the amount returned from the last function `e` is returned - I'm assuming in the background they are getting returned but then overwritten?

Comment: In order to get that sort of recursion, I think you would have to pass in the previous delegate as a parameter.  Otherwise, you are only adding 10 + 6 = 16.

Comment: @DavinTryon That's not really recursion.  There isn't any function calling itself; it's just chaining of functions.

Comment: @Servy Ah yes, more like "nested" functions?  Is there a functional language name for that?

Comment: @DavinTryon ...that is exactly what is happening - it returns 16

Comment: Another issue is exceptions.  If one of the methods threw and exception, you wouldn't programmatically know which one it was nor would you know what methods weren't executed.

Comment: Dupe: [multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748434/multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you have a multicast delegate like `d` in your question, the return value is the return value from the ***last*** method of the invocation list of `d`.

In general, for multicast delegates, it is most natural to use return type `void`.

The compiler had no chance to guess that you were hoping for `10+2+3+4+5+6`. You didn't specify it anywhere.

You could change your delegate type into:

```
delegate void del(int xToAdd, ref int sum);
```

Then your method `a`, for example, should look like this:

```
private void a(int x, ref int sum) { Console.WriteLine("a is called"); sum += x + 2; }
```

The multicast delegate instance `d` would then be called like this:

```
int sum = 0;
d(10, ref sum);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

That's not how return types are handled for delegates.  What will happen is that all of the handlers will be executed independently of each other, and then one will be chosen at random (technically it's the handler that was subscribed last, but you shouldn't rely on that) to be returned to the caller that invoked the delegate.

I would highly discourage you from ever using an event (you are treating this delegate as if it's an event) that has a return value.  The behavior is virtually never desirable.  If you want a return value it makes sense to ensure that your delegate is always mapped to exactly one function, no more, no less.

As for actually generating the desired result, while there are a number of approaches, you would be better served with a more traditional collection of delegates:

```
List<Func<int, int>> functions = new List<Func<int, int>>();
//populate

int result = functions.Aggregate(10, (total, func) => func(total));
```

Comment: The methods in the invocation list are called in order, the return value of the last of those calls is used (it's not chosen at random), an you **can** rely on that. To quote the C# spec: _"Invocation of a delegate instance whose invocation list contains multiple entries proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the invocation list, synchronously, in order."_ And further the return value _"will come from the invocation of the last delegate in the list."_ Same paragraph also guarantees that `ref` parameters can be used, like the way I do it in my answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, I know that.  That doesn't change the fact that it is very bad practice to rely on it, not because it's undefined and could change, but because it's not well known, and not behavior that readers of the code would *expect* to be well defined.  It also becomes highly difficult to reason about in a multithreaded environment, which is particularly common when dealing with events in this manor.  My answer is clear about this; it is indeed *possible*, it's just a very bad idea.

Comment: You're right it's a bad idea. Delegate types that are meant to be multicast (meaning that delegate combination ("plus") is to be used), which includes all delegate types meant to be used for events, should always return `void` and have no `out` parameters. Then a `ref` parameter can be used to accumulate/aggregate a value from all the methods ("subscribers" in event jargon).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Even that is something I would discourage the use of.  Among other problems, it very tightly couples the event with *every single event handler*.  All of the event handlers need to know that it's an aggregate value, and they need to treat it as one (as opposed to not touching it, blanking it out, etc.).  It also means that the event needs to know that it's being used to aggregate data, which it generally doesn't need to know.  It also makes it responsible for giving it a seed, and doesn't allow event handlers to be independent of each other.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen While I stand by the answer I've provided as what I would suggest as the way to solve the problem, if you felt strongly that a single delegate needs to be used it would be preferable to have the handlers close over a variable to be used as the accumulator, rather than using the `ref` parameter, as it would avoid at least many (but not all) of the problems I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: +1 thanks for all the information chaps - currently filling lists via Lambda functions are a bit over my head

Comment: @whytheq Well, it's as simple as `functions.add(p.a);`  There is no need at all to use a lambda, although you can if you want.

Comment: I'm fine with a `List<Func<int, int>>`, but are you going to check that every member `f` in the `List<>` satifies `f.GetInvocationList().Length == 1`? Because if some `f` consists of two or more "atoms", then we have the situation again where intermediate return values are discarded.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen This is why I discourage ever using a delegate that's not an `event` as referring to multiple methods, despite the fact that virtually all delegates in C# can be used in that way.  Rather than explicitly checking in code, I think that the intent is quite clear from looking at the code that each delegate should only refer to a single method, and that could be explicitly stated in documentation if you felt it was needed.  This is the behavior that I find most all developer expect, which is another reason why I dislike your solution of treating a non-event as an event.