# Delegate Combination Misbehavior

Tags: c#, delegates

Give the following piece of code:

```
List<string> aux = new List<string>();

aux.Add("a");
aux.Add("ab");
aux.Add("ac");
aux.Add("abc");
aux.Add("b");
aux.Add("bc");
aux.Add("c");
aux.Add("e");
aux.Add("f");

Func<string, bool> searchForA = (f => f.Contains("a"));
Func<string, bool> searchForC = (f => f.Contains("c"));
Func<string, bool> searchForF = (f => f.Contains("f"));
```

Can someone please explain to me why this call

```
aux.Where(searchForA + searchForF + searchForC).ToList();
```

returns "ac", "abc", "bc" and "c" which is the same result as

```
aux.Where(searchForC).ToList();
```

I mean, wheres "a" and "ab" and "F" on the first query?

EDIT: I used the delegate combination because I want to define dynamically the search pattern!

EDIT2: Major edit check for new piece of example code, this the problem im tryng to solve

```
string[] searchFor = "a c f".Split(' ');

Func<string, bool>[] delegates = new Func<string, bool>[searchFor.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < searchFor.Length; i++)
{
    string search = searchFor[i]; // Make sure the lambda does not capture a loop variable!
    delegates[i] = new Func<string, bool>(f => f.Contains(search));
}

List<string> aux = new List<string>(); 
aux.Add("a");
aux.Add("ab");
aux.Add("ac");
aux.Add("abc");
aux.Add("b");
aux.Add("bc");
aux.Add("c");
aux.Add("e");
aux.Add("f");

List<string> result = aux.Where((Func<string, bool>)Delegate.Combine(delegates)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't know what `+` does for delegates, but you should use `||` or `&&`.

Comment: @HighCore the logical operators "AND" and "OR" are not valid for delegates

Comment: @Leonardo you're right. Then it should be `.Where(x => SearchForA(x) || searchForC(x))`

Comment: Your newly added code has an "access to modified closure" bug. Each delegate is closed over the *same variable `i`* and so by the time the delegates run, `i` will be out of range. I'll fix your code.

Comment: Dupe: [multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748434/multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Invoking the combination of two non-void returning delegates has the semantics "call the first, discard the result, call the second, return the result".  It doesn't have the semantics "call them both and `or` the results if they happen to return `bool`". Remember, delegate combination has to work for any delegate type; why should the runtime choose `or` semantics for bool-returning delegates instead of `and` semantics? What should it do for delegates that return `string`, concatenate the strings?  If you combine `int` returning delegates should it add the numbers?

The problem of combining results is not solvable in a consistent way, so the choice is to ignore all but the last.

If you want to `or` two predicates together then you can easily do so yourself. Here's a handy extension method:

```
static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this Func<T, bool> f1, Func<T, bool> f2)
{ return t => f1(t) || f2(t); }
```

and now you can say

```
...Where(searchForA.Or(searchForC).Or(searchForF))...
```

You could also extend that to multiple delegates:

```
static Func<T, bool> OrMany<T>(params Func<T, bool>[] fs)
{ 
    Func<T, bool> result = t => false;
    foreach(Func<T, bool> f in fs)
        result = result.Or(f);
    return result;
}
```

And now you can use "expanded form" with a list of delegates:

```
...Where(OrMany(searchForA, searchForC, searchForf))...
```

or "unexpanded form" with an array of delegates:

```
Func<string, bool>[] delegates = whatever;
...Where(OrMany(delegates))...
```

Comment: Thank you! you almost understood my original problem... the thing is that i want to search using more than 2 delegates... i futher edited the question

Comment: @Leonardo: You can use the `Or` helper I gave you to combine any number of delegates.

Comment: I futher edited but it seems you figured it out with the OrMany... ill test it

Comment: @Leonardo: I fixed a bug in your code. You can use my `OrMany` method to combine your array of delegates.

Comment: you just got another fan! tks alot!