# Multicast delegate of type Func (with return value)?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```cs
Func<string, string> func1 = (param) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Func 1 executing");
    return "Hello" + param;
};
Func<string, string> func2 = (param) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Func 2 executing");
    return "World" + param;
};
Func<string, string> funcSum = func1 + func2;
string funcResult = funcSum("!");
Console.WriteLine(funcResult);
```

The output is:

```
Func 1 executing
Func 2 executing
World!
```

Inverting the sum:

```cs
Func<string, string> funcSum = func2 + func1;
```

Gives the output:

```
Func 2 executing
Func 1 executing
Hello!
```

My initial test was done with a boolean return type, and the returned value was also always determined by the last function. Is it working as intended? Aren't we losing the return value of the other functions? If so, is there a use case in real world of those multicast delegate of functions?

Comment: Dupe: [multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748434/multicast-delegate-weird-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is it working as intended?

It's working as specified, at least. Whether that's what you intended or not is a different matter :) From section 15.4 of the C# 5 specification - emphasis mine:

> Invocation of a delegate instance whose invocation list contains multiple entries proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the invocation list, synchronously, in order. Each method so called is passed the same set of arguments as was given to the delegate instance. If such a delegate invocation includes reference parameters (§10.6.1.2), each method invocation will occur with a reference to the same variable; changes to that variable by one method in the invocation list will be visible to methods further down the invocation list. **If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a return value, their final value will come from the invocation of the last delegate in the list.**

Next:

> Aren't we losing the return value of the other functions?

Yes, at the moment.

> If so, is there a use case in real world of those multicast delegate of functions?

Very rarely, to be honest. However, you can split a multicast delegate apart, using [`Delegate.GetInvocationList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.getinvocationlist):

```
foreach (Func<string, string> func in funcSum.GetInvocationList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(func("!"));
}
```

Comment: Multicast delegates are crucial for events - and `Func` is probably supported for consistency?

Comment: @Yoga: I didn't say multicast delegates were pointless - I agreed with the supposition that in the real world, multicast delegates of functions (non-void delegates) are rare. The conventional event pattern uses void delegate types. Note that delegate combination predates Func entirely... But yes, the effect of combined non-void delegates is basically for consistency IMO. And you *can* get at the bits, after all...

Comment: To be honest, if I were asked for a better solution, I would be unable to give an answer or alternative overflowing of good sense. And in addition, it's Microsoft and a full team of pros we are talking about, so I'm not arguing with that (no irony intended).

Answer (score 7):

Most of your question has been answered already, but one thing that's missing is a real-world use case for this. Here's one: asynchronous event handlers.

```
public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event AsyncEventHandler X;
public async Task OnX(EventArgs e) {
  // ...

  var @event = X;
  if (@event != null)
    await Task.WhenAll(
      Array.ConvertAll(
        @event.GetInvocationList(),
        d => ((AsyncEventHandler)d)(this, e)));
}
```

This allows the user of the class to simply write

```
myobject.X += async (sender, e) => { ... };
```

but the object will still ensure that `OnX`'s task doesn't complete until the event handler's has.

Answer (score 5):

The multicast delegate will always return the result of the last function. Because there is no predefined way to combine or chain the `T` results.

If you want to obtain all the results along the chain, try this :

```
    var result = "!";
    foreach (Func<string, string> func in funcSum.GetInvocationList())
    {
        result = func(result);
    }
```