# Return Arrays using Func.Invoke

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to use Funcs to return an array of objects using the invoke method?

I'm wanting to make a more easy way to get values by other scripts subscribing to the instance who is going to use thes values and invoke them when they needed, mostly to avoid Much memory alocation for this type of datas (Using it ta make some game tools for organizing and modular usage).

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
public class FuncArrayReturn : MonoBehaviour
{
    Func<int, int[]> TestFunc;
    int[] testReturn;
    int RandomNumber()
    {
        return UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 10);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        TestFunc  += RandomNumber;
        testReturn = TestFunc?.Invoke();
    }    
}
```

Expecting to return an array of all of the values.

Comment: "Is it possible to use Funcs to return an array of objects using the invoke method?" Yes. But your `RandomNumber` method returns a *single* random number, and doesn't take any inputs, so it would only be compatible with `Func<int>`, not `Func<int, int[]>`.

Comment: Well, I intended to get only the number from the subscriber without the need if referencing an array (The array only being the result after the invoke). When I try to subscribe the number to return it later, it expects the array as well.

Comment: "_I intended to get olhy the number from the subscriber without the need if referencing an array_" Then you cannot directly subscribe/assign the subscriber to `Func<int, int[]>`, obviously. Wrap the RandomNumber method call in a lambda expression or anonymous function that satisfies the signature of Func<int, int[]> and creates the int array. Then assign this to TestFunc, e.g., `TestFunc = (int input) => new int[] { RandomNumber() };` or something like that...

Comment: I don't understand any of what you mean by that, I'm afraid. Note that "subscriber" suggests an event, which you haven't mentioned anywhere. I'm still pretty confused about what you're trying to do, or how you expect a method that just returns a single number to be used for a delegate that returns an array.

Comment: "I don't understand any of what you mean by that, I'm afraid." Trying to explain better, basically, I have an array of values, and the func that returns an array in a script. What I'm wanting is: other scripts to be able to subscribe a value/method for this Func, and when needed invoke this methods to assign tho this inside array.

Comment: Other type inconsistency problems notwithstanding, I don't think that you would want to use `+=` either.  I think you just want `=`.  If you combine multiple functions into a  _multicast delegate_ with `+=` like that, then when you call it, all the functions will execute, but you'll only get the return result of the ___last___ one.  See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12530888/1563833)

Comment: I wonder if you're looking for the pattern of `Enumerable.Repeat(0, N).Select(yourFunction).ToArray()` to call `yourFunction` N times and return the results as an array.

Comment: " If you combine multiple functions into a multicast delegate with += like that, then when you call it, all the functions will execute, but you'll only get the return result of the last one." That's mostly the problem i'm having. I'm Trying to get all the results encapsulated in an array.

Comment: "I wonder if you're looking for the pattern of Enumerable.Repeat(0, N).Select(yourFunction).ToArray() to call yourFunction N times and return the results as an array" Looking a little about it now (I'm really a Novice in programming right now), the execucion you said makes sense to what i'm after. I'm basically wanting to make something similar to that, but working like an event

Answer (score 0):

As I was searching for solutions to my issue, I found an simple way to make it work

```
public static class Groupable<TGroupable>
{    
    public static TGroupable[] Agrupar(Func<TGroupable> func)
    {
        //List That'l hold the final values
        List<TGroupable> groupables = new List<TGroupable>();
        //List of methods subscribed to the Func separated individually
        List<Func<TGroupable>> actions = func.GetInvocationList().Cast<Func<TGroupable>>().ToList();
        //Invoking every method, adding it to the early created list
        actions.ForEach(x => groupables.Add(x()));
        //Returning final result
        return groupables.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This method was able to return the final values processed individualy in an array, as I intended.

Thanks for all the sugestions and the attention delivered in this question.