# Delegate in c++

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

Hey i want to implement delegate in c++ i know how to do in c# i posting my code but don't know how i convert this to c++

```
public class Events {
    public delegate void Action();
    public Action OnPrintTheText = delegate{};
}

public class ABC {
    private Event evt;
    public ABC() {
        evt  = new Event();
    }
    public void printText() {
        evt.OnPrintTheText();
    }
    public Event getEventHandler() {
        return evt;
    }
}
public class Drived {
    private ABC abc;

    public Drived() {
        abc = new ABC();
        abc.getEventHandle().OnPrintTheText += OnPrint;
    }
    ~Drived() {
        abc.getEventHandle().OnPrintTheText -= OnPrint;
    }
    public void OnPrint() {
        Debug.Log("ABC");
    }
}
```

now whenever i call printText it will automatically call the OnPrint() of Drived class so is there anyway to implement this to c++?

Comment: Have a look at pure virtual functions and abstract classes. A delegate is nothing more than a degenerate source/sink interface declaration with either just one particular function. Function pointers are also similar.

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement that in C++/CLI?

Comment: This is an amazing article on C++ delegates: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Answer (score 1):

C# does a lot of management behind the scenes. Broadly, a delegate in C# is a container of function references.

In C++, you can create a similar delegate by using a functor template that wraps an object instance and a member function for class member functions, and also one that just wraps a function (for non members). Then you can use a standard container to maintain the list/array/map/etc of the instances of the functors, and this will provide you with the functionality of the C# delegate and also allow adding and removing 'actions' (C#:  += and -=).

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132149/callback-function-c/22133873#22133873) on how you can create such a templated functor for class members. The non-member case is simpler since it does not wrap an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at function pointers:
http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

A function pointer is a pointer that points to a specific function, basically what a delegate is.

Look at this:
[What is the difference between delegate in c# and function pointer in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097244/what-is-the-difference-between-delegate-in-c-sharp-and-function-pointer-in-c)

Comment: An example and explanation would be very useful here. Just pointing to a link is not acceptable on SO.